# método para borrar registros por su nombre de usuario

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas intento hacer un metodo para borrar registros por su nombre de usuario, realizado el codigo y  no da fallos, pero al actualizar la bbdd no se ha eliminado, he realizado otras operaciones y funcionan bien, incluso borrar registros desde sql, pero java no.

```
    Connection c=null;
    Statement s=null;
    
    try {
        c=createconnection();
        s=c.createStatement();
        int valor=s.executeUpdate("delete from Usuario where NOMBRE='"+nombre+"'");
        
        
        if(valor==1) {
            System.out.print("ok");
        }else {
            System.out.print("no");
        }
        if(s!=null) {
            s.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        disconnect(c);
    }
```

Comment: Hola SteelKidneys, bienvenido, para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida, te sugiero que la edites, quites las imágenes que contienen código y mensajes de error, y agregues estos como texto, también evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: ¿Verificaste lo que hay en `nombre` y si realmente hay filas que coincidan con ese dato? Sería aclaratorio que nos digas por dónde entra el código, es decir, qué imprime en pantalla. Dicho eso, deberías pensar no muy tarde en implementar consultas preparadas, ya que el código actual, si funcionase, supondría un gravísimo riesgo de seguridad porque permitiría ataques de *inyección SQL*.